# Passing focus of child element in a UserControl to parent in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a complex WPF UserControl made of other ContentControl templates which contain sets of buttons, textfields, and other elements.

The parent UC is focusable so I have a style with a property trigger to update (gratuitous OuterGlowBitmapEffect) when the UC has focus. However when the user clicks or tabs to any of the buttons inside the UC the focus is lost.  I would like to maintain the glow while using the UC.

Can I pass the focus from the child controls up to the UC?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be able to base your property trigger on the [IsKeyboardFocusWithin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.iskeyboardfocuswithin.aspx) property, which returns true if any child element has focus.